# How to configure spring boot jpa configurations for entities in intellij

Tags: spring, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have used spring boot and spring data jpa but when I created a named query in entity I see 'can't resolve symbol 'User'',I have tried it in intellij..

How I can resolve that problem ?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FJCX.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@NamedQuery(name = "updateRole",query = "select u from User u ") //that line
public class User extends AbstractPersistable{
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Column(name = "first_name")
```

Comment: do you expect people to know without seeing the JPA Entity and mapping, and the named query? Being psychic only goes so far ...

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: is it enough that code ?@NeilStockton @abarisone

Comment: Maybe you table name in the query should be Users and not User?

Comment: it is not native query.it is jpql.

Comment: What gives the exception? Intellij, or at runtime? if runtime post the stack trace. If Intellij, then Intellij's message is completely wrong. The class+annotations are totally valid.

Comment: Yes intellij gives the exception

Comment: Do you have the jpa facet enabled?

Comment: If your Intellij config is correct then raise a bug on Intellij for flagging valid code as invalid.

Comment: @TobiasTimm No because of i have used spring boot that it has not any config file for jpa persistence.xml or etc..only it has application properties

Comment: @cihanbulut i also dont have a persistence.xml in my project, but needed to add the jpa facet without any further configuration for my jql to work

Comment: @cihanbulut everything looks good from code perspective I have a similar thing in my project but i use eclipse. if you are using gradle maybe you need to add this to it [apply plugin: 'idea']